# Solve a linear ordinary differential equation

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Solve $ \dfrac{1}{x^2+1}\dfrac{dy}{dx} + xy = 3$, with $y(0) = 0$.

Rearrange the equation I get

$ \dfrac{dy}{dx} +(x^3+x)y = 3x^2 +3$

and the integrating factor is $$r(x) = e^{(\int x^3+x) dx} = e^{\dfrac{x^4}{4}+ \dfrac{x^2}{2}}$$

Multiply the integrating factor to both side of the equation I get

$$ye^{\dfrac{x^4}{4}+ \dfrac{x^2}{2}} = \int (3x^2+3)e^{\dfrac{x^4}{4}+ \dfrac{x^2}{2}} dx$$

Is it possible to integrate the integral on the right side? Or should I just leave the solution as a definite integral?

$Edit$

Take account of the initial value $y(0) = 0$, is the following equation correct?(Using Fundamental Theorem of Calculus)
$$y =\dfrac{ \int_{0}^{x} (3t^2+3)e^{\dfrac{t^4}{4}+ \dfrac{t^2}{2}} dt}{e^{\dfrac{x^4}{4}+ \dfrac{x^2}{2}}}$$

Comment: I do not think you can get a closed form.

Comment: (Maybe the right side should have been 3x instead of 3.)

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal, I have edited my question, could you please take another look?

Comment: @user84413, I double checked the problem, the right side is $3$ not $3x$

Comment: It looks like you worked it correctly, for the problem as written.

Comment: @user84413: Your answer is correct.